# How to generate code coverage with running lcov program at the same time

Tags: lcov

I have a large project with unittest binaries running on the other machines. So, the gcda files were generated on the other machines. Then, I download them to the local machine but the different dirs. Each of the dirs has the sources code.

For example: dir `gcda1/src/{*.gcda, *.gcno, *.h, *.cpp}...`, dir `gcda2/src/{*.gcda, *.gcno, *.h, *.cpp}...`.

Because the project is very large, so I have to run multiple lcov processes at the same time to generate info files to save time. And then merge these info files.

The problem is, when I merge these info files, it will take dir infos, for example:

```
gcda1/src/unittest1.cpp
gcda2/src/unittest1.cpp
```

I want this:

```
src/unittest1.cpp
#src/unittest1.cpp # this is expected to merge with above
```

The commands I use:

```
$ cd gcda1
$ lcov --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 -c -d ./ -b ./ --no-external -o gcda1.info
$ cd ../gcda2
$ lcov --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 -c -d ./ -b ./ --no-external -o gcda2.info
$ cd ..
$ lcov -a gcda1/gcda1.info -a gcda1/gcda2.info -o gcda.info
$ genhtml gcda.info -o output
```

The root dir contains the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

Well, I have found a method to solve this problem finally.

The info files `lcov` generated are plain text file. So we can edit them directly.

Once you open these files, you will see every file line start with `SF`. Like below:

```
SF:/path/to/your/source/code.h
SF:/path/to/your/source/code.cpp
...
```

## Problem

In my problem, these will be:

```
// file gcda1.info
SF:/path/to/root_dir/gcda1/src/unittest1.cpp
```

```
// file gcda2.info
SF:/path/to/root_dir/gcda2/src/unittest1.cpp
```

And, after `lcov` merge, it will be:

```
// file gcda.info
SF:/path/to/root_dir/gcda1/src/unittest1.cpp
SF:/path/to/root_dir/gcda2/src/unittest1.cpp
```

But, I expect this:

```
// file gcda.info
SF:/path/to/root_dir/src/unittest1.cpp
```

## Method

My method to solve the problem is editing the info files directly.

First, edit `gcda1.info` and `gcda2.info`, change `/path/to/root_dir/gcda1/src/unittest1.cpp` to `/path/to/root_dir/src/unittest1.cpp`, and `/path/to/root_dir/gcda2/src/unittest1.cpp` to `/path/to/root_dir/src/unittest1.cpp`.

Then merge them like below and generate html report:

```
$ lcov -a gcda1.info -a gcda2.info -o gcda.info
$ genhtml gcda.info -o output
```

In a large project, we could not manually edit each info file, otherwise you will collapse.

We can use `sed` to help us. Like below:

```
$ sed "s/\(^SF.*\/\)gcda[0-9]+\/\(.*\)/\1\2/g" gcda_tmp.info > gcda.info
```